# How to prevent vaadin component from resizing?

Tags: java, vaadin

I use Vaadin 10.
So I have 2 vertical layouts inside another vertical layout. And I set my expand ratios like this:

```
mainVerticalLayout.setFlexGrow(3, verticalLayout1);
mainVerticalLayout.setFlexGrow(1, verticalLayout2);
```

The problem is when I add too many components to verticalLayout2 - it becomes bigger and takes almost half of the page (also scroll bar appears, but that's not a problem). I want it to stay the same size.

Comment: Even when you explicity set the height with `verticalLayout2.setHeight()` ?

Comment: @Jay then it shows components outside the layout like this: https://imgur.com/a/BfkACG1

Comment: I can't get to imgur through the work Web Filter